# Mirror repeat textures

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

As far as I know  Blender uses OpenGL. OpenGL provides an option to mirror repeat a texture beyond its bound. (UV coordinates outside the range 0-1)

Is there a way to mirror a texture that way in Blender?

I've seen in a similar question that in pre-2.8 versions there was a tab named 'Image scroll mapping' where you were able to mirror the texture. Seems like this feature is gone? In 2.8+ there is a way to repeat the texture in the 'Image texture' node but not mirrored. But in the textures tab on the right you can mirror it under 'Mappings'. However I'm not able to use textures of the texture tab in my image texture node. Just as a brush.

I know that I could create the mirror effect with different math nodes... just wonder if there is a more simply way? If not maybe they could bring this feature from pre-2.8 versions back?

Thanks for help.

---

sorry about my bad (?) english :)